# Can I combine two domains under a single account without losing the 50 users limit?

Tags: google-workspace

Currently I have two Google Apps accounts created before the 10 users limit, but now I need to migrate about 20+ users from domain A.com to domain B.net, the last one is empty, just the admin account. That's only to avoid reconfiguring the clients and don't lose contact with the old (A.com) domain.

To test it, I create an alias in domain C.com with a new domain D.net, originally C.com has 50 users limit, but when I create the alias, it went down to just 10, don't mind really, I'm just using 4 account in C.com.

But A.com AND B.net have 50 users limit, so I'm gonna lose the limit if I delete the B.net Google Apps account and then create it's alias in A.com?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you delete B.net Google Apps account, you will loose the licenses assigned to it.

This is because Google Apps accounts can't be merged and licenses can't be transferred from one domain account to another domain account.

**References**
[Merge domains from separate accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4417332?hl=en)